# tabs component is not loading when page refresh in Ionic 3 and Angular project

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am working on the Ionic tabs project. For the first time, the tabs are displaying properly, but when I change anything in my code or when page refresh the tabs are not displaying. To see the tabs again we need to run the application again and I found that the tabs component is not loading when page refresh. For the first time that is after login, I am loading the tabs component by using `this.navCtrl.push(TabsPage);`. The same thing I used in `ionViewDidLoad()` but its loading the tabs component multiple times. How can I achieve this in my application?

Comment: It will be hard to help you without any code.. also "tabs component is not loading": is there an error message? This could be precised too "when I change any thing in my code", what did you change?

Comment: I have not get any error message.what did i mean "when I change any thing in my code" is when some changes happen to my code the project will automatically reload at that time also tabs are disappearing.